# SQLException - Connection reset error

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am trying to establish a jdbc connection with SQL Server 2008 R2, using the SQLJDBC4 jar file and JDK 1.6. I am using Netbeans IDE and have added the SQLJDBC4 jar and added the path to the database in the 'databases' section in the services. The code is as below:

```
package connect2;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Connect2 {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

   Connection conn;
        conn = null;
           System.out.println("Done....");

           try
           {

               Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

               conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:sqlserver://172.17.39.13\\CRM:1433;databaseName=crm_xchanging","crm_xchanging","Welcome001");
               System.out.println ("Database connection established");


           }
           catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
           {
               System.out.println (e);
           }
           catch (SQLException ex)
           {
               System.out.println(" error");
           }


          finally
         {
             if (conn != null)
              {

                       try{

               Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  usertable");
                System.out.println("User Name: " );
                        while (res.next()) {
                                String employeeName = res.getString("user_name");
                                System.out.println(employeeName);
                                            }
                    conn.close();
    }
                 catch(SQLException ex){
  System.err.println("SQLException information");

  while(ex!=null) {
  System.err.println ("Error msg: " + ex.getMessage());
  System.err.println ("SQLSTATE: " + ex.getSQLState());
  System.err.println ("Error code: " + ex.getErrorCode());
  ex = ex.getNextException(); 
// For drivers that support chained exceptions
  }}




               }
           }

       }

   }
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
run:
Done....
Database connection established
SQLException information
Error msg: Connection reset
SQLSTATE: 08S01
Error code: 0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

I don't think there is any mistake in the code or the JDK. I have also tried to set the max no. of active connections for SQL Server as 0 (infinite). How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You have to debug and see the InnerException to know what make Error

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific? How can you do that in Netbeans?

Answer (score 1):

There is a known bug introduced in Java 6u29 that causes SSL failure specifically with SQL Server 2008 R2. [An Atlassian Fisheye troubleshooting page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fishkb/java-sql-sqlexception-i-o-error-connection-reset-when-connecting-to-an-external-sql-server-2008-database-284365810.html) suggests a fix was incomplete.

> Oracle delivered a fix in 6u30, although for at least one affected
>   client not even Java 1.7 worked.

On my development team we have found this bug to impact Java 8 at as well. One of the recommendation in the Fisheye article is to disable CBC protection using a JVM flag and that has also worked for me for SSL Java 8 SSL with a SQL Server 2008 R2 connection.

`-Djsse.enableCBCProtection=false`

The other suggestion is to revert to Java 1.6.0_24.